# Morphia Query on Array of Subdocuments using elem

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following document structure in mongodb collection "Contact". There is an array of subdocuments called "numbers":

```
{
    "name" : "Bill",
    "numbers" : [
        {
            "type" : "home",
            "number" : "01234",
        },
        {
            "type" : "business",
            "number" : "99099"
        },
        {
            "type" : "fax",
            "number" : "77777"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I want to query only for "home" and "business" numbers, I can do something like this in mongodb-shell:

```
db.Contact.find({ numbers: { $elemMatch: { 
        type : { $in : ["home", "business"]}, 
        number: { $regex : "^012" }
}}});
```

But how to do this in morphia? Is there any way?

I understand "$elemMatch" is supported in morphia. So I could do something like:

```
query.filter("numbers elem", ???);
```

But how exactly do I add a combined query for the subdocument?

Answer (score 2):

It is too late, but maybe others can find it handy.

I found that solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/FlEjBoSqkhg

```
query.filter("numbers elem", 
BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
.push("type").add("$in", new String[]{"home", "business"}).pop()
.push("number").add("$regex", "^012").pop().get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using morphia, consider using [jongo](http://jongo.org/). It lets you query MongoDB as you were using MongoDB shell. Furthermore, it will give you more freedom when mapping your array elements. Here is how your example will look with jongo:

```
contacts_collection.find("{numbers : {$elemMatch: {
                                         type: {$in :#},
                                         number: {$regex: #}  
                                                  }
                                     }
                          }", 
                         new String[]{"home", "business"}, "^012")
                   .as(Contact.class);
```

Note that, if you only need a single number object (or multiple) from the array you can use a custom result mapper/handler. You just have to substitute **.as(Contact.class)** with :

```
.map(new ResultHandler<Number>() {...})
```

For a full example take a look at my [blog post](http://ingini.org/2013/04/03/mongodb-with-jongo-sleeves-up/) or at my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ihr/jongo-by-example)